# Apache and Mysql not starting

Tags: mysql, apache

Xampp Ver 5.5 installed in windows 10 pro 64bit, apache and mysql services are not starting automatically. Tried all solution provided earlier. Can some one help

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes they wont start because other processes would be running on the same port number as of apache and mysql. Go to task manager processes, end the tasks that are running on that port and start your apache and mysql server

Comment: No I found issue with 10 pro license